# Custom UITableViewCell width issue

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a custom UITableViewCell with and .xib. In the xib I have set the cell width to 320.

I want to position a UIlabel inside the cell relative to the cell width. However, in the code during runtime the Bounds.width of the cell is always 320, as set in the xib, and not the actual width of the screen/UITableView which I need to position the UILabel correctly.

The width should be different for iphone 5, 6 and 6+ obviously, at least during runtime, but it's always set to 320 on all devices. What am I missing?

Thanks!

EDIT

Here is a tiny bit of code.

```
var newFrame = _lblDetail.Frame;
newFrame.X = Bounds.Width - 55; //get current width of cell, and subtract 55 and set that as the X value of the frame for the label
_lblDetail.Frame = newFrame; //set new frame on label
```

Comment: Did you check the width of the table view? Is it 320 as well? Could you please add some codes or relevant screenshots?

Comment: Yes, the width of the tableview is also 320. Added a bit of code

Answer (score 1):

The tableview of the cell always has a width of 320 tells that the table is not responding to the screen size. What you need to do is then to check whether your auto-layout constraints of the table view is set properly (if you're using auto-layout) or whether the frame of the table view is set differently for each screen size.

Comment: This is incorrect, the table cell width will match the width of the window, which increases for each device, upto a width of 414 for iPhone 6+ http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Bounds.Width
```

Will be 320 for the iPhone 4S & 5, 375 for the iPhone 6 and 414 for the iPhone 6+.

The fact you are seeing 320 as the width, makes me believe that your app has does not support higher density screens yet and will be scaling the 320 up. You can tell as the status bar (time at the top) will be slightly bigger.

Set the respective launch images for each device size and your all will run at the native resolution for each device.

You need to set launch images at the following resolutions:

```
Default-667h@2x.png for iPhone 6; dimensions 750x1334
Default-736h@3x.png for iPhone 6 Plus; dimensions 1242x2208
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get width in `layoutSubviews` method.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    NSLog("self.frame.size is %@", NSStringFromCGSize(self.frame.size))
}
```

below is my output

> 2015-07-21 10:10:34.942 MyApp[74669:1208599] self.frame.size is {768, 310}